# generate all combination of params

Tags: python

I have dictionary (space_of_params) of all possible values of parameters and I need to generate all possible combination of parameters into dictionaries. Number of keys (parameters) in the input dictionary is not fixed and may vary.

I have input dict with varying number of definions of params:

```
space_of_params = {'param1':range(1,5),'param2':['a','b','c'],'param3'[True,False],....}
```

And I need to generate all combination of params into dicts:

```
{'param1':1, 'param2':a, 'param3': True}
{'param1':1, 'param2':b, 'param3': True}
{'param1':1, 'param2':c, 'param3': True}
{'param1':1, 'param2':a, 'param3': False}
{'param1':1, 'param2':b, 'param3': False}
{'param1':1, 'param2':c, 'param3': False}
```

And so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` in this way:

```
from itertools import product

lst = [dict(zip(params, v)) for v in product(*space_of_params.values())]
```

This will produce a list, and if you print it, you will get your desired result:

```
for item in lst:
    print item

{'param3': True, 'param2': 'a', 'param1': 1}
{'param3': True, 'param2': 'a', 'param1': 2}
{'param3': True, 'param2': 'a', 'param1': 3}
{'param3': True, 'param2': 'a', 'param1': 4}
{'param3': True, 'param2': 'b', 'param1': 1}
{'param3': True, 'param2': 'b', 'param1': 2}
{'param3': True, 'param2': 'b', 'param1': 3}
{'param3': True, 'param2': 'b', 'param1': 4}
{'param3': True, 'param2': 'c', 'param1': 1}
{'param3': True, 'param2': 'c', 'param1': 2}
{'param3': True, 'param2': 'c', 'param1': 3}
{'param3': True, 'param2': 'c', 'param1': 4}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can write a custom made algorithm for this, my guess is that you better write some logic around the `itertools.product` function:

```
from itertools import product

def dict_product(**args):
    tupargs = list(args.items())
    keys = list(map(lambda x:x[0],tupargs))
    for item in product(*map(lambda x:x[1],tupargs)):
        yield dict(zip(keys,item))
```

This generates:

```
>>> space_of_params = {'param1':range(1,5),'param2':['a','b','c'],'param3':[True,False]}
>>> list(dict_product(**space_of_params))
[{'param1': 1, 'param2': 'a', 'param3': True}, {'param1': 1, 'param2': 'a', 'param3': False}, {'param1': 1, 'param2': 'b', 'param3': True}, {'param1': 1, 'param2': 'b', 'param3': False}, {'param1': 1, 'param2': 'c', 'param3': True}, {'param1': 1, 'param2': 'c', 'param3': False}, {'param1': 2, 'param2': 'a', 'param3': True}, {'param1': 2, 'param2': 'a', 'param3': False}, {'param1': 2, 'param2': 'b', 'param3': True}, {'param1': 2, 'param2': 'b', 'param3': False}, {'param1': 2, 'param2': 'c', 'param3': True}, {'param1': 2, 'param2': 'c', 'param3': False}, {'param1': 3, 'param2': 'a', 'param3': True}, {'param1': 3, 'param2': 'a', 'param3': False}, {'param1': 3, 'param2': 'b', 'param3': True}, {'param1': 3, 'param2': 'b', 'param3': False}, {'param1': 3, 'param2': 'c', 'param3': True}, {'param1': 3, 'param2': 'c', 'param3': False}, {'param1': 4, 'param2': 'a', 'param3': True}, {'param1': 4, 'param2': 'a', 'param3': False}, {'param1': 4, 'param2': 'b', 'param3': True}, {'param1': 4, 'param2': 'b', 'param3': False}, {'param1': 4, 'param2': 'c', 'param3': True}, {'param1': 4, 'param2': 'c', 'param3': False}]
```

What we thus first do is convert the dictionary to a list of key-value tuples. Next we construct all `product`s of the values of the dictionary and `zip` them with the `keys` we have extracted from the dictionary into a new dictionary.